# Rails 4 - postgresql 9.4 jsonb does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, jsonb

I have used rails 4 and postgresql 9.4 in my project.when i was run "rdd && rdc && rdm && rds" and i got this error **PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "jsonb" does not exist** how do solve this error? tell me.

My migrate file:

```
class CreateConsultingLocationDoctorSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :consulting_location_doctor_schedules do |t|
           t.belongs_to :consulting_location_doctor
           t.datetime :schedule_date, null: false
           t.jsonb :slot_details, index: true, default: {}
           t.daterange :start_and_end_time, null: false
           t.datetime :deleted_at
           t.belongs_to :deleted_by

           t.timestamps
      end
   end
end
```

Thanks for ur help!

Comment: That would indicate that your Rails version isn't actually 4.2 since at least your format is right and the necessary versions are 4.2 for Rails and 9.4 for PostgreSQL. Could you check that carefully?

Comment: I have the same issue I am using rails 4.2 and pg 9.4.1 have you found any solution ??

Comment: The duplicated question and solution are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393562/rails-and-jsonb-type-jsonb-does-not-exist

Answer (score 7):

Check that you are connected to the right Postgres instance in development.

```
rails console
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select version();").first["version"]
```

If you're sure you are running 9.4, then it might be that you have two Postgres servers running. One 9.4, and an older one.

I ran into this problem and edited my database.yml and specified `host: 'localhost'`.

Comment: In my case correct postgres was running on 5433 port.