# Rails and jsonb type "jsonb" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.1

rails -v
Rails 4.2.0
```

I added a jsonb column through migration like that

```
class AddPreferencesToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :preferences, :jsonb, null: false, default: '{}'
    add_index :users, :preferences, using: :gin
  end
end
```

I get this error :

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "jsonb" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT 'jsonb'::regtype::oid
```

any help ?

Comment: i saw this problem the other day too, seems there hasn't been any solution to this. could you try upgrading to 4.2.1 or downgrading your rails

Comment: @argentum47 I think it's my fault, I will fix it and post the answer. thank you.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

After looking around I discovered that my postgresql version is not 9.4 by running the right command

```
postgres=# SHOW SERVER_VERSION;
server_version 
----------------
9.1
```

So I had simply to upgrade my postgresql to 9.4.

By the way I followed [this article](http://www.gab.lc/articles/migration_postgresql_9-3_to_9-4) to do the upgrading which I found very handy.

Now :

```
postgres=# SHOW SERVER_VERSION;
 server_version 
----------------
 9.4.1
```

Hope this help someone in the same situation.

Comment: Correct. Upgrading postgresql version helps. This [other upgrading guide](https://medium.com/@tk512/upgrading-postgresql-from-9-3-to-9-4-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-2b4ddcd26535) works as well.

Comment: The guide is for most debian systems - but there is a bit more that needs to be done for Ubuntu 14.04 (which does not have the postgres-9.4 package/repository). For older versions of Ubuntu, search on askubuntu.com as there is a plethora of solutions there.

Comment: for anyone else coming across this, I used [this article](https://medium.com/@tk512/upgrading-postgresql-from-9-4-to-9-5-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-dfd93773d4a5) and successfully upgraded directly from Postgres 9.3 to 10.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. The article is for 9.4 -> 9.5 but works well for 9.3 -> 10.5 !

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/633923/428475) are the instructions which guides in installing postgres-9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04